# Can I reset WP Rocket cache from console (mac/windows)

Tags: wordpress

I would like to clear cache from console just after releasing changes from github to production server. Now I have to click manually from admin panel.

Answer (score 2):

1. Connect to your sever via SSH
2. Run `wp package install wp-media/wp-rocket-cli`
   [This plugin](https://github.com/wp-media/wp-rocket-cli) will allow you to clear the cache from the terminal
3. Run `wp rocket clean`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it with a very simple PHP script that you can trigger with a console command:

https://docs.wp-rocket.me/article/494-how-to-clear-cache-via-cron-job

Basically, create a PHP file that just runs the function `rocket_clean_domain()` and trigger that script to run with the console.

**clean-cache.php**

```
<?php 
    require_once( 'wp-load.php' );

    if( function_exists( 'rocket_clean_domain' ) ){
        rocket_clean_domain();
    }
?>
```

Comment: I would like to fire it on server from mac terminal. How to fire function you mentioned above?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Mac Terminal, but you should just be able to run a cURL command to it: `curl --silent http://www.yourdomain.com/clean-cache.php > /dev/null`